# What values are allowed for the IsMimeMultipartContent subtype parameter

Tags: c#, .net, mime, system.net

I am working on an image file upload method in Web API 2 and have noticed that the extension method `IsMimeMultipartContent` can take a `string subtype` parameter, as documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh835657(v%3Dvs.118)

However, the only specification for this parameter is "The MIME multipart subtype to match." and no examples of format are present in the documentation.

I presume that, as a `string` value, it must take a value such as "image/png".  Is there a way for it to check against all images, such as using a wildcard value "image/*" or value separated by semicolons on commas?  What is the required format of this parameter?

If it can't check for multiple MIME types, is there a better way to check?

Comment: I have tried uploading a PNG image with the value set to "image/png" to no avail.  I have little idea what this parameter is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `string subtype` parameter is a multipart MIME subtype.  It is appended to the mime type `multipart/` and compared to the incoming MIME type of the data, as such:

```
content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType.Equals("multipart/" + subtype, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

This has been taken from the source code, publicly visible [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/HttpContentMultipartExtensions.cs).

It will not work with `image/png` because it looks for `multipart/<subtype>` MIME types.

Typical valid subtypes are `form-data` and `byteranges`.  More can be read about [MIME types and subtypes here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types).